# How does 'Tv mode' translate to shutter priority mode?

Tags: canon, camera-basics, shooting-mode, shutter-priority

What do the **T** and **v** stand for?

[image: Picture of Canon mode dial.]
<sub>Public-domain image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:CanonEOS100TopLeft.JPG).</sub>

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7477/do-any-other-manufacturers-other-than-canon-use-the-terms-av-and-tv, and my answer there.

Comment: There's some argument in the comments/answers to the other question over whether the `V` is _value_ or _variable_.

Comment: Also, as a geek, I am tempted to answer the question in the title with "1:1, of course!"

Comment: @mattdm - "1:1" would be better, but the system won't let you submit that short answer...

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Tv stands for "Time value". Similarly Av stands for "Aperture value".

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_priority

Comment: Not that I don't appreciate your quick helpfulness, @Vikas. :)

Comment: @mattdm +1 just for you buddy

Comment: @rfusca: funny. But I'm serious that it's detrimental to the site to over-upvote trivial answers, because it causes the really great answers to be relatively undervalued as they get buried under quick things like this.

Comment: Additionally, while I believe the answer to be correct, the linked source is actually quite poor, as it's merely an unsourced wikipedia article with nothing to back it. See http://dougkerr.net/Pumpkin/articles/APEX.pdf for a better one.

Answer (score 3):

TV stands for Time Value. This is basically to indicate that you can set the Shutter Speed manually and the aperture will set automatically depending on the other parameters you've set like the exposure and the ISO. This mode is very handy in case of bird photography, sports photography or anything where shutter speed needs to be constant.

Comment: I think time value is just poor translation . Speed value would be more to the point. Ken

Comment: @Ken I disagree. "Duration" would be better, as the value (i.e., 1/5 s, 1 s, etc) is in units of time, whereas speed is relative to unit of 1/time (i.e., Hz).